# Azure B2C - RESTful Technical profile / Long running requests / timeouts

Tags: azure, rest, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Consider an Azure B2C - Business API integration, where a custom policy triggers an HTTP request (req A.) to  business apis (REST API on AWS) for provisioning access to external systems.

Req A response time is currently limited by AWS/API Gateway to 30s but this is changing with requirements and might increase.

Considering Req A is so expensive, what options do we have in the custom policy for handling this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in B2C Custom Policies specifically to handle this case. So your options are probably limited to whatever else you'd usually do for any API.

A few examples:

- Cacheing: Instead of calling AWS API Gateway for the inquiry, you'd call another service which caches these results (like Azure API Management). This may or may not be a good idea depending on what type of claim you're grabbing.
- Delayed Retrieval: Instead of populating the claim in the user token via B2C custom policy, have your application grab that value independently of Azure AD B2C.